# SQL join conditions

Tags: sql, count, group-by, inner-join

Three tables

```
cats
=============
id
cat_herder_id
size
color
birthday

collars
=============
id
cat_id
diameter
color
material

cat_herders
=============
id
name
age
height
```

I want to get a row for each cat herder that is over a meter tall with a count of the number of cats that were born in February that are orange with black collars that belong to that herder and a count of all the cats that are orange with blue collars the belong to each herder, how would I go about doing a query of that sort.

I don't think I can simply specify in the where statement because my count appears to be off, I am grouping by cat_herders.id

EDIT: Less sanitized, less abstracted version of what I have so far:

```
SELECT company.tblusers.first_name, company.tblusers.last_name, company.tblusers.userid, SUM(db.tasks.estimated_nonrecurring+db.tasks.estimated_recurring), COUNT(sugarcrm2.ncr_ncr.id),  
SUM(db.batch_log.time_elapsed) FROM company.tblusers 
INNER JOIN db.batch_log ON company.tblusers.userid = db.batch_log.userid 
INNER JOIN db.tasks ON db.batch_log.batch_id = db.tasks.batch_id
INNER JOIN sugarcrm2.ncr_ncr ON company.tblusers.first_name + " " + company.tblusers.first_name = sugarcrm2.ncr_ncr.employee
WHERE  departmentid = 8 AND DATE(db.batch_log.start_time) =  DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY userid
```

Comment: You are talking about 2 separate queries - the orange cats w/blue collars is a separate count unrelated to the first, unless you want a field for each collar color

Comment: It sounds like 2 queries.  Also if this is homework tag it as such.  Also post what SQL you do have so far.

Comment: Homework problem or some kind of puzzle????

Comment: Neither, I was just concerned about sanitizing table names and fields and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: Depending on your RDBMS and the datatype of the `cats.birthday` column, you'll probably need to adjust this query to extract the birth month, but this gives you the general idea.

```
SELECT ch.name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.color = 'orange' AND cl.color = 'black' AND c.birthday = 'February' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OrangeCatsBlackCollarsFeb,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.color = 'orange' AND cl.color = 'blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OrangeCatsBlueCollars 
    FROM cat_herders ch
        LEFT JOIN cats c
            INNER JOIN collars cl
                ON c.id = cl.cat_id
            ON ch.id = c.cat_herder_id
    WHERE ch.height > 1 /* in meters */
    GROUP BY ch.name
```